# “Push something to the back”

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context: I pushed a very heavy and big box, but according to law of action and reaction, the box was pushed to the front, and I was pushed to the back.

Can I say “I pushed the box to the back” in this context?

Comment: No. It should read, "I pushed *forward* on the box and the box pushed *backwards* against me. To say something was "pushed to the front/back" means it was pushed into the front/back of the room, or whatever area it was in.

Comment: @gotube Thank you, gotube.

Comment: It's not true that the box pushed you back  what happened was that the inertia of the box and the friction between the box and the floor resisted or impeded the force you applied. There had to have been an imbalance of forces or the box would not have moved.